# 12v SLA charging, when do I have to stop?

Tags: batteries

I have a used 12v SLA which I got from a computer UPS. I want to charge it but I don't have a specific charger to charge it. But I have a 12v car battery charger. If I connect the battery to that charger at what voltage should I stop charging?  I already did that and  disconnected the battery when it was 14.4v (checked while the battery was still charging) when I disconnect the battery from the charger voltage goes down to 13.3v in about 1minute. is it normal or the battery is dead?

Comment: 13.3V is good voltage for a 12V lead acid battery.

Comment: well in 5mins it goes to 13v

Comment: I don't think this is enough information to conclude if the battery is dead or not. I suggest some kind of test where you use the battery to drive a load for a certain amount of time.

Comment: ok I will run my 10w LED and test the time. at what voltage should i disconnect the led ?

Comment: Look up some state of charge curves.  For longest life pick the endpoint voltage that will leave 40-60% of charge in your battery and calculate the theoretical capacity but only use the top half of the charge in practice for long life.  Sealed Lead Acid cells HATE deep discharge and can only do it a dozen times usually before they are compromised. High purity Cyclon cells are more robust but also more expensive.  -  http://www.enersys.com

Comment: See [Testing the condition of an SLA](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/49783/2191)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it fully charged, you need to charge it to 14.4 V and wait until the current has dropped to almost nothing. This CV phase of the charging is called absorption and is what puts it from 80 % state of charge to 100 %. If you have no means of measuring the current, you can estimate the time needed to the same as it took from 0-80 %. If you leave it connected to 14.4 V for extended time, you will slowly outgas the water as hydrogen and oxygen. For a flooded battery, just refill it with destilled water. For a sealed battery, any hydrogen and oxygen which does not recombine within the battery is lost forever and performance will suffer permanently.

After you disconnect the charger, the battery will fall quickly to 13 V and if you wait even longer, you will see 12.6 V. It's still fully charged.

I could not find a picture online with state of charge plotted along with voltage and current so you just have to take my word for it. Here is a 24 V battery so just divide voltages by 2 for your 12 V battery: [image]